# How to do a dual alignment (right and VCenter) in Python PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, alignment

I am trying to align an item both horizontally on the right and vertically in the center.
There are 2 single functions that work:

```
setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
```

and

```
setAlignment(Qt.AlignVCenter)
```

But when the 2 functions are combined (one after the other), the result is that only the last one is applied (and the first one is forgotten).

How to get the alignment I want (horizontal right and vertical center)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setAlignment` accepts alignment flag or flags combination, you can build flag combination with bitwise `or` operator

```
setAlignment(Qt.AlignVCenter | Qt.AlignRight)
```